# Categories tags in module (mod_articles_categories)

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to display tags of every sub category in categories list module (mod_articles_categories).
For articles in similar module (mod_articles_news) I always do something like this:

```
<?php $itemtags = (new JHelperTags)->getItemTags('com_content.article', $item->id);
$taglayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags');
foreach ($itemtags as $tag) { echo $tag->title; } ?>
```

But code like this doesn't work fork categories even I change 'com_content.article' to 'com_content.category'

Maybe someone knows what I doin' wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I got the solution:

```
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :
$itemtags = (new JHelperTags)->getItemTags('com_content.category', $item->id);
$taglayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags');?>
<?php if (!empty($itemtags)) { foreach ($itemtags as $tag) { echo $tag->title.' '; }; } ?>
<div><?php echo $item->title; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```